# Solr Highlight Unexpected Result with NGramTokenizer

Tags: solr, highlight

I try to highlight part of the word in Solr 5.3. I am using NGramTokenizer and minGramSize = 3, also maxGramSize = 3.

The schema is:

```
<field name="ngram" type="text_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="3"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have a document like this:

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "ngram": "Seatac is beside Seattle",
        "_version_": 1542785459119194000
}
```

I search `q = sea`,

I **expected** to get both of the two "sea" in the sentence highlighted separately, which should be `<em>sea</em>tac is beside <em>sea</em>ttle`

**However**, what I got is:

```
"1": {
      "ngram": [
        "<em>Seatac is beside Sea</em>ttle"
      ]
}
```

Does anyone have idea why it happened and how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: can you check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8212

Comment: I just checked this. Although I don't think my bug is about the MAX_NUM_TOKENS_PER_GROUP = 50, plus the FastVectorHighlighter doesn't work for me, the PostingsHighlighter works!!!  Thank you.

Comment: I found there is another issue when I use PostingsHighlighter. The phrase " " dosen't work during PostingsHighlighter. For instance, querying q ="sea", should only highlight <em>sea</em>tac is beside <em>sea</em>ttle. But now, it highlights every s, e, and a.